# Puedo Usar delete() o deleteMany() para borrar documentos de una mongodb sin borrarlos todos?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

mi pregunta surge a que si quiero borrar un doc lo puedo hacer o cuando quiero borrar todos los documentos, pero cuando quiero borrar una X cantidad me los borra todos y no tengo idea como hacer que no borre todos los docs del colletion:

```
getlinkUser: function(req, res) {
    var user = req.params.user;
    var ids = req.params._id;
    var active = req.params.condition;
    var limit = parseInt(5); //parseInt(req.params.limit);

    if (limit == undefined) limit = 1 
    if (limit == null) limit = 1 

    Link.find({ user: user, active: true }).limit(limit).sort({ systemTime: 1 })
        .then((user) => {

            if (user == null) {
                res.status(200).send({ enlaces: "No tiene fotos en este usuario" })
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({ enlaces: user })
            }

        }).catch((err) => {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: err,
                Red Social: 'Contactame para verificar tu error!',
            });
        })
}
```

entonces lo que quiero hacer en este código es que me borre solo una parte, ya que cuando le agrego  esto:

```
.deleteMany({ user: user})
```

me borra todos los enlaces de fotos que tengo en el doc

```
{
"enlaces": {
    "n": 7,
    "opTime": {
        "ts": "6752705216660897799",
        "t": 6
    },
    "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000006",
    "ok": 1,
    "operationTime": "6752705216660897799",
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": "6752705216660897799",
        "signature": {
            "hash": "zs9b9LxvRpg5TnDvB7mJaqXz+PA=",
            "keyId": "6749287797082816513"
        }
    },
    "deletedCount": 7 // tenia 5 par borrar en limit y me borro los 7 que tenia
}
```

}

alguien me da una idea de como hacer?

Comment: Quieres borrar X cantidad de documentos de una colección, pero sin decir cuáles. ¿Esa es tu pregunta? Porque es lo que parece que deseas hacer, no pasas filtros ni nada a tu consulta. En tu método find sólo pones un límite, por lo tanto serán devueltos los primeros X documentos encontrados. ¿Luego quieres borrar esos mismos? No es muy intuitivo o eficiente eso, ya que no tienes control sobre lo que te devolverá la consulta. Por favor aclara un poco lo que deseas lograr. Saludos

Comment: saludos, en la primera consulta si paso filtro para el meyhod fin(),  Link.find({ user: user, active: true }) ese es el filtro, el usuario y si el enlace tiene condicion como true ( si esta activo o no ) y tambien .sort({ systemTime: 1 }) para que la consulta me salga desde el primero que guardo hasta el ultimo por orden de documento, por ID y como fue guardado, lo que deseo hacer es que luego que saque ese resultado, me borre ese resultado como si fuese el methodo FindOneAndDelete() pero no uno solo si no mas de un documento.